# Load JavaScript files from jar when running js-test-driver

Tags: javascript, gradle, js-test-driver

Is there a way to load JavaScript files from jars when running tests with js-test-driver? I'd like to find a solution that works both from command line and from Eclipse.

The reason I want to solve this is that I'm trying to do a gradle build and store artifacts on a repository. The artifacts (jars) contain Java as well as JavaScript files, and when running the JavaScript unit tests with js-test-driver, I have dependencies to JavaScript files inside the jars.

One solution is to unpack the jars and run js-test-driver normally. Is there a better solution without the unpacking?